# HTML content is displaying as plain text

Tags: html, angularjs, html-escape-characters

I am trying to display a link using `<a>` in a modal window, but the content is showing as a plain text; however, the same text in another modal window is displaying properly.

This is my code:

```
<span data-ng-if="error.message">{{error.message}}</span>
```

Comment: Have a look at $sce to display text as html in an angular app

Comment: paste your code please.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: My HTML code is like this
<span data-ng-if="error.message">{{error.message}}</span>

Comment: `<span>` is not `<a>`. A span is just text inside another block or inline element. If you want an anchor (`<a>`) it should look something like this:  `<a href="#" data-ng-if="error.message">{{error.message}}</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a link in HTML the code should be

`<a href="{yourURL}">TEXT HERE</a>`

But it would be more helpful if you posted up your code for us to see where the mistake is.

Comment: My HTML code is 
<span data-ng-if="error.message">{{error.message}}</span>
 and the message is coming from a angular service

var service = {

            getErrorMsg: function(errorcode) {
                        var  errorMsg = "";
                        errorMsg = USER_FRIENDLY_MSG[errorcode];
                        $log.info( "errorMsg :" + errorMsg);
                        return errorMsg;
                    }
            };